# Add radio button column in kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show radio button in kendo Grid column. I have tried so many methods. Its showing only header in row not showing radio button. I am working in MVC4

My code :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<razor.Core.BOL.TRD_OrderItem>()
                    .Name("Grid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(item => item.OrderId).Hidden(true);
                        columns.Template(item => @Html.RadioButton("Approve", true, false, new { @id = "Approve" })).Title("Approve");
                        columns.Bound(m => m.MatchType).Title("Match Type");
                        columns.Bound(item => item.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("Date");
                        columns.Bound(item => item.OrderType).Title("Sell");
                        columns.Bound(item => item.Description).Title("Ask");
                        columns.Bound(item => item.OrderAmount).Title("Total");
                        columns.Bound(item => item.OrderStatus).Title("Status");
                    })
                                     .Pageable()
                                     .Sortable()
                                     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                     .Ajax()
                                     .PageSize(10)
                                      .Model(model =>
                                      {
                                          model.Id(m => m.OrderId);
                                      })
                                      .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrderOption", "Order", new { OrderId = ViewBag.OrderId}))
                        ))
```

Thanks,

S Somu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the radio button was bound to the model, so you should add a field to save the radiobutton value (Approved), so following your example I added my radio button column with:

```
columns.Bound(item => item.Approved).Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='radio' name='ItemList[#= index(data)#].Approved' value='true' />").Title("Approve");
```

Where *ItemList* is the name of your List of TRD_OrderItem in your model.

Also you will need to add this javascript function that is used to get the index for the radiobutton name field:

```
function index(dataItem) {
    var data = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();

    return data.indexOf(dataItem);
}
```